# Plugging in a value after taking partial derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, symbolic

I am trying to write a code where I have a function of two variables, take the partial derivative with respect to each variable and finally plugs in specific values for the variables. To be more specific I first want to take the partial derivative of the function bs (symbolic) and then in that expression plug in a some specific value into it to get a numerical result.
Something seems to go wrong, in the output I get a bunch of terms of the form Pattern^(1,0) and I don't know what they mean.

```
ϵ = 0.1; 
a = 1; 
b = 1; 

bs[gs_, gd_] := (-ϵ)*gs + (a/3)*((m + n + 4)*gs + 12*gd)*
    gs + (b/9)*((2*m*n + 5*m + 5*n + 27)*gs^2 + 6*(m*n + 14)*gd^2 + 
      12*(2*m + 2*n + 5)*gs*gd)*gs; 

x = D[bs[gs_, gd_], gs]; 
m=1;
n=1;

x1 = x /. gs -> 0 /. gd -> 0
```

In that example I tried plugging in 0 for both variables. But in general I want to plug in expressions like `gd = (3 ϵ)/(m*n + 8)`. My knowledge of Mathematica is quite basic so I apologize if this is a simple question and appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! The underscore in the argument of function definition represents a [`Blank`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) pattern (read more about patterns in [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html)). Therefore, when "using" your function `bs`, you should not put underscores next to arguments. Simply use `x = D[bs[gs, gd], gs]`.

Comment: Try examplary `Derivative[1,2][bs][0,0]` if you want to substitude values after differentiation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest if you just define a new function like:

```
dbs[gs_, gd_] = D[bs[gs, gd], gs]
```

Note I didn't use the underscore in the derivative construct rather only on the left side when defining a function.  Now you can use:

```
    m = 1;
    n = 1;
    dbs[gs, (3 \[Epsilon])/(m*n + 8)]

(* -0.1 + 2 gs + 1/3 (0.4 + 6 gs) + 1/9 gs (3.6 + 78 gs) + 
 1/9 (0.1 + 3.6 gs + 39 gs^2) *)
```

If you want to get good with Mathematica, start reviewing the questions here and study the answers.  Copy/Paste the solution into a notebook and break it down and study each term.  Nothing wrong with asking simple question here as long as you post  Mathematica code of your attempt to solve the problem.